# How can I parse two subnodes in an XML value into SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, nodes

I have the following XML:

```
<xmlRoot>
  <DomainName>sample.com</DomainName>
  <UserCountsByTemplate>
    <KeyValueOfstringint>
      <Key>default</d2p1:Key>
      <Value>20</d2p1:Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringint>
    <KeyValueOfstringint>
      <Key>basic</d2p1:Key>
      <Value>66</d2p1:Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringint>
  </UserCountsByTemplate>
</xmlRoot>
```

I am trying to get two rows to be returned like so:

```
Domain      TemplateName  TemplateCount
----------  ------------  -------------
sample.com  default       20
sample.com  basic         66
```

I have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @info XML
SELECT @info = '<xmlRoot><DomainName>sample.com</DomainName><UserCountsByTemplate><KeyValueOfstringint><Key>default</Key><Value>20</Value></KeyValueOfstringint><KeyValueOfstringint><Key>basic</Key><Value>66</Value></KeyValueOfstringint></UserCountsByTemplate></xmlRoot>'
SELECT 
      row.value('DomainName[1]','NVARCHAR(255)') AS [DomainName]
    , row2.value('.','NVARCHAR(255)') AS [TemplateName]
    , row3.value('.','INT') AS [TemplateCount]
FROM @info.nodes('/xmlRoot[1]') T1(row)
CROSS APPLY @info.nodes('/xmlRoot/UserCountsByTemplate/KeyValueOfstringint/Key') T2(row2)
CROSS APPLY @info.nodes('/xmlRoot/UserCountsByTemplate/KeyValueOfstringint/Value') T3(row3)
```

But get the following results:

```
Domain      TemplateName  TemplateCount
----------  ------------  -------------
sample.com  default       20
sample.com  basic         20
sample.com  default       66
sample.com  basic         66
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correlating your access to Key and your access to value - so you're effectively producing a cross join between all keys and all values.

```
DECLARE @info XML
SELECT @info = '<xmlRoot><DomainName>sample.com</DomainName><UserCountsByTemplate><KeyValueOfstringint><Key>default</Key><Value>20</Value></KeyValueOfstringint><KeyValueOfstringint><Key>basic</Key><Value>66</Value></KeyValueOfstringint></UserCountsByTemplate></xmlRoot>'
SELECT 
      row.value('DomainName[1]','NVARCHAR(255)') AS [DomainName]
    , row2.value('Key[1]','NVARCHAR(255)') AS [TemplateName]
    , row2.value('Value[1]','INT') AS [TemplateCount]
FROM @info.nodes('/xmlRoot[1]') T1(row)
CROSS APPLY @info.nodes('/xmlRoot/UserCountsByTemplate/KeyValueOfstringint') T2(row2)
```

Instead, I'm extracting the `KeyValueOfstringInt` nodes, and then accessing different elements in the `value()` calls. But both `value()` calls are operating on the *same* node (for each row).